# logic for distinguishing advice seekers vs. advice givers

Tags: php, logic

What's a good logic to use for distinguishing an advice seeker from an advice giver (aside from looking for question marks)? Right now I'm using very simple logic in PHP to identify keywords typically used by advice seekers/givers, but perhaps someone else has a better idea. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some machine learning method? The Naive Bayes algorithm should work well for such a task.

Comment: any idea what the data set would look like? Should i keep my keywords method and use that as the input, or use entire posts as input?

Comment: The simplest method would be the bag-of-words approach, that is, you would simply feed the algorithm with a list of the words contained in the text, with or without the word count. You could test this method first without the word count, then with the word count, to see if it gives an acceptable accuracy for the classifier; if it fails, you could then try bigrams, trigrams, etc...
In a nutshell, you'd have to experiment first to see which approach works best for your case.